# Unity GUI combo box with search

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need a list which is a lot of list (enum list). And right now the list is using the pop up (combo box), but the normal combo box is not really help because too many item inside it. It kind of frustrating when try to select item that is far away at bottom. The list are full on the screen when openned.

[image: List Picture]

When openning a combo box and type a letter it will jump only the first letter, when I press second letter the list will be jump to another first letter start. So example, I want to select DIAMOND -> I press D and it will go to the list with D start. And when I press I, it will jump to item that start with I instead of DI.

Is there any component of GUI to have the search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity haven't components for search like your.

But you can try something like this (`SearchEnumLabel` function):

```c#
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;

public enum States
{
    ABCDEF,
    ACBDEF,
    AdEXG,
    bErDSa
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectControllerTester))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class ObjectControllerTesterEditor : Editor
{
    States _selected;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
    {
        _selected = SearchEnumLabel("My search enum", _selected);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("[Debug]Current selected: "+_selected);
    }

    private String _searchEnumText = "";
    private bool _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch = false;
    private T SearchEnumLabel<T>(String label, T state) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("T must be an enumerated type");
            return state;
        }
        var states = Enum.GetValues(typeof (T)).Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchEnumText) && states.Length > 0) _searchEnumText = state.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var text = EditorGUILayout.TextField(label, _searchEnumText);
        if (text != _searchEnumText || _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch)
        {
            _searchEnumText = text;
            var mach = states.Select((v,i)=>new {value = v, index = i}).FirstOrDefault(a => a.value.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower()));
            var targetState = state;
            if (mach != null) targetState = (T) Enum.GetValues(typeof (T)).GetValue(mach.index);
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Select closest: "+targetState);
            Repaint();
            state = targetState;
            _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch = !string.Equals(_searchEnumText, targetState.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

This script will show something like this:

Default view

[image: Default vision]

After input some data

[image: After input some data]

**=== UPDATE ===**

More complex variant with fast select buttons

```c#
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public enum States
{
    ABCDEF,
    ACBDEF,
    AdEXG,
    bErDSa,
    sEOjsfl,
    SdDiaso,
    POsdjaow,
    PSADJsd,
    Oasdo,
    IOQWEnds
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectControllerTester))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class ObjectControllerTesterEditor : Editor
{
    States _selected;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        _selected = SearchEnumLabel("My search enum", _selected);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("[Debug]Current selected: " + _selected);
    }

    private String _searchEnumText = "";
    private bool _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch = false;
    private T SearchEnumLabel<T>(String label, T state) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("T must be an enumerated type");
            return state;
        }
        var states = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchEnumText) && states.Length > 0) _searchEnumText = state.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var text = EditorGUILayout.TextField(label, _searchEnumText);
        if (text != _searchEnumText || _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch)
        {
            _searchEnumText = text;
            var mach = states.Select((v, i) => new { value = v, index = i }).Where(a => a.value.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower())).ToList();
            var targetState = state;
            if (mach.Any())
            {
                // many of results
                targetState = (T)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).GetValue(mach[0].index);
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Select closested: " + targetState);
                Repaint();
                var selected = GUILayout.SelectionGrid(-1, mach.Select(v => v.value).ToArray(), 4);
                if (selected != -1)
                {
                    targetState = (T)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).GetValue(mach[selected].index);
                    _searchEnumText = targetState.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch = false;
                    GUI.FocusControl("FocusAway");
                    Repaint();
                }
            }
            state = targetState;
            _isSearchEnumLabelInSearch = !string.Equals(_searchEnumText, targetState.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

Tap button to select target enum
[image: Tap to button to select target enum]

Comment: Hi @Randomyr, thanks for you answer. I just thinking that about list of the enum on a new window open. So its like a button next to object field that we can click and open window. So all enum list will be there, and we can filter and select the enum we want. Is that possible?

Comment: @Apin, I have updated answer - are you mean this case?

Comment: Hi @Randomyr, That was one a way around. What i am thinking is open a dialog, like on object field. But this is already help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, you can replace 'EnumNBEvent' as you like.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using Newborn.Pb.Event;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Protobuf.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(EnumNBEvent), false)]
public class FSMEventDrawer : PropertyDrawer {

    struct EnumStringValuePair : IComparable<EnumStringValuePair>
    {
        public string strValue;
        public int intValue;

        public int CompareTo(EnumStringValuePair another)
        {
            if (intValue < another.intValue)
                return -1;
            else if (intValue > another.intValue)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    Dictionary<int, string> filters = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    //string filter = string.Empty;
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        int y = (int)position.position.y;
        if (!filters.ContainsKey(y))
            filters[y] = string.Empty;
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 100, 20), property.name);
        filters[y] = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x + 100, position.y, 60, 15), filters[y]);
        List<EnumStringValuePair> enumList = GetEnumList(filters[y]);
        List<string> enumStrList = new List<string>(enumList.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < enumList.Count; ++i)
        {
            enumStrList.Add(enumList[i].strValue);
        }
        int selectedIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < enumList.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (enumList[i].intValue == property.enumValueIndex)
            {
                selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        selectedIndex = EditorGUI.Popup(new Rect(position.x + 170, position.y, 200, 20), selectedIndex, enumStrList.ToArray());
        if (enumList.Count > selectedIndex)
        {
            property.enumValueIndex = enumList[selectedIndex].intValue;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    private List<EnumStringValuePair> GetEnumList(string filter)
    {
        List<EnumStringValuePair> allList = new List<EnumStringValuePair>();
        Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumNBEvent));

        for (int i = 0; i < enumValues.Length; ++i)
        {
            EnumStringValuePair pair = new EnumStringValuePair();
            pair.strValue = enumValues.GetValue(i).ToString();
            pair.intValue = (int)enumValues.GetValue(i);

            allList.Add(pair);
        }

        List<EnumStringValuePair> ret = new List<EnumStringValuePair>();
        Regex regex = new Regex(filter.ToLower());
        for (int i = 0; i < allList.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(allList[i].strValue.ToLower()))
            {
                ret.Add(allList[i]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```